# Tell Browsers to replace UTF-8 word break character with hyphen?

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I just explored the great UTF-8 character `\u200b`, which tells Browsers where it can break a word, if it doesn't fit it's parent container:

`MySuperLongWordThat\u200bWontFitItsParentContainer`

will be displayed as

`MySuperLongWordThat`

`WontFitItsParentContainer`

Is there any way to tell the Browser to automatically replace `\u200b` with a hyphen `-` in case the word will break?

I thought about replacing it manually with JavaScript, but I do not know any event that will fire when the word breaks.

Comment: These word breaks won't be handled by JavaScript but the displaying engine of the browser when shown on the page.

Comment: You can also use the CSS `word-break: break-all;` property to achieve this.

Comment: Would defeat the purpose of using it if you replace it

Comment: @Svenskunganka That will also break words even if there's no actual need to. For better results use `word-wrap: break-word;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what zero-width space is intended for.

The CSS [`hyphens`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens) property can be used to help, but you'll notice from that documentation that if you want to manually insert word-wrap points then you should use `&shy;` - the "soft-hyphen".